# Cakephp inside folder online

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, directory

I have a cakephp app inside a folder online like this: https://www.example.com/main

however, when I enter there, I want my url to show like this: https://www.example.com

I already tried modifying core.php

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', '/');
```

And it shows what I want but returns "The requested URL /info/inicio was not found on this server."

I know that the solution would be to just remove the folder "main" and load the cakephp app directly, but at the moment that's not possible.

Comment: I you have access to the apache configuration, you can modify the `DocumentRoot` to point to the right folder. If not, through `.htaccess` is also possible to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going to my cpanel and setting https://www.example.com/main as the pointer and then created a new domain that points to https://www.example.com/admin

Easy